# Correlated subquery using multiple tables

Tags: sql, mariadb, correlated-subquery

I have some problem with some tasks.

I've got many tasks like this: Create a query that shows up for every client, ID of his last invoice (name, surname, ID of last invoice, invoice date)

Here are the tables:

Table "Clients":

| ClientID | Surname | Name | Pesel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 01234 |
| etc | etc | etc | etc |

Pesel is a polish person id

Table "Invoices":

| InvoiceID | InvoiceDate | ClientID | PaymentMethod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F1/2020 | 01.01.2020 | 1 | Cash |
| etc | etc | etc | etc |

I must do it using correlated subquery with aliases. I know how it works with comparing records from single table, but how to do it with two of them?

The example I've got from a teacher is like:

```sql
SELECT a.subject, a.grade, a.data
FROM students_grade AS a
WHERE data = ( 
               SELECT MAX( data )
               FROM students_grade AS b
               WHERE a.subject = b.subject );
```

And I need to do it simillar

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Comment: Both the main query and the subquery can use multiple tables. In your case the main query will be a `join` of Customers and Invoices (if no subqueries exist it should show Customers and ALL Invoice details); just put it the way you want your columns. Then add the `where` condition with the subquery. This subquery will be finding the MAX(InvoiceDate) for the ClientID from the main query. After attempting these share your problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it goes as per your example using 1 and 2 'invoices', and then joining 'clients':

```
select c.name, c.surname
     , i1.InvoiceID as `ID of last invoice`
     , i1.InvoiceDate as `invoice date`
from invoices i1
left join clients c on c.ClientID = i1.ClientID
where i1.InvoiceDate = ( select max(i2.InvoiceDate)
                         from invoices i2
                         where i2.ClientID = i1.ClientID)
```

dbfiddle for your sample data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=812993d467842f789848ef873156cbc0) (MariaDB 10.3)

Comment: Thanks, it worked but I needed to change LEFT JOIN on INNER JOIN because of another table from DB that have also ClientID so LEFT JOIN returned many NULL records. But it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Doing a correlated subquery can be expensive.  By pre-querying the max() invoice date per client and JOINING should be better performance.

```
select
      PQ.ClientID,
      c.SurName,
      c.Name,
      i.InvoiceID,
      i.InvoiceDate
   from
      ( select
              clientID,
              max( InvoiceDate ) MaxDate
           from
              invoices
           group by
              clientID ) PQ
         JOIN Invoices i
            on PQ.ClientID = i.ClientID
           AND PQ.MaxDate = i.InvoiceDate
         JOIN Client c
            on PQ.ClientID = c.ClientID
```